# Restore orientation to that of the phone

Tags: android

I have a videoview in my app, and a button to switch to fullscreen. Now when you press this button you might be in portrait mode, so when the user presses the fullscreen button I force Landscape orientation with:

```
getActivity().setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
```

But in this fullscreen mode of my video, if the user presses the "exit fullscreen mode" button, I would like to restore the app to the orientation of the phone. However if I request

```
getResources().getConfiguration().orientation
```

this gives me the current configuration of my app, which in this case is always landscape.

The result is that my app remains in landscape mode and never switches back when I rotate the phone.

How can I tell my app to just go back to applying the phone orientation?

Comment: Can you not save the current orientation before you set the requested orientation to landscape?

Comment: no, the user might change orientation during the video

Comment: So? You'd still be going back to the saved orientation before the video started, right?

Answer (score 0):

Use SCREEN_ORIENTATION_USER.  This will set it to the users preferred orientation, which if the user hasn't overridden it will set it to the sensor result.  Or if the user has overridden it (I lock my phone into portrait myself) it will respect that.